# The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query using two tables I got the following message:

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

I am SQL ignorant.

```
FROM [UIC ROSTER] 
INNER JOIN [Azusa RSP] ON [UIC ROSTER].UIC = [Azusa RSP].UIC
```

Comment: Is that the exact query? There's no `SELECT` statement.

Comment: show all the code  ..

Comment: Have you tried doing:

`FROM [UIC ROSTER] as a INNER JOIN [Azusa RSP] as b ON a.UIC = b.UIC`